# Python subprocess output read error

Tags: python, subprocess, output, tshark

I have a command which works great at the terminal:

```
sudo tshark -V -l -i "any" -f 'udp port 4729'
```

I trying to read the output from my python script:

```
import subprocess
command = ['tshark', '-V', '-l', '-i', '"any"', '-f', '"udp port 4729"']  # the shell command
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)
output, error = process.communicate()
print output
```

It does not work. Maybe it's some troubles with writing a command in the list.

I receive the error:

```
gooman@ubuntu:~/workspace/glade_tests/src$ sudo ./main.py
tshark: Lua: Error during loading:
 [string "/usr/share/wireshark/init.lua"]:45: dofile has been disabled
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on "any"
tshark: The capture session could not be initiated (No such device exists).
Please check to make sure you have sufficient permissions, and that you have the proper interface or pipe specified.
0 packets captured
```

Comment: What happens if you alo add sudo to the list `['sudo', 'tshark', ...]` and add `stderr = None, shell = True` to `Popen`?

Comment: Why are you using `subprocess.Popen` rather than simple `subprocess.call`? What happens if you use `subprocess.call`? Also, note that `Popen` starts a [new process (in which directory?)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), so it should be easier to debug with `call`.

Comment: Try `output = subprocess.check_output(command)`.

Comment: @User: don't use `shell=True` and the list argument. It is an error in most cases.

Comment: @Gooman: drop `""` inside arguments, there is no shell to interpret them i.e., use `output = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split("""sudo tshark -V -l -i "any" -f 'udp port 4729'"""))`

Answer (score 0):

Thy this:

```
import subprocess

command = "sudo tshark -V -l -i "any" -f 'udp port 4729'"
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print "An error has been occured", e
    raise

print "The subprocess output:", output
```

Maybe, it will be needed to add stdout=subprocess.PIPE argument.